# Trouble getting input form to return 'success' message and to reset

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a form based on the bootstrapious.com contact form tutorial. In my case I have changed it to populate a mysql database. Filling out the form and submitting it does get the information correctly in the database, but does not return a 'success' message or reset the form. I think the problem is in my javascript but am not sure. I would appreciate any help.  Thanks

Here is my html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Family Member</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='custom.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>   
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">

                    <h1>Family Member Form</h1>

                    <p class="lead">Please enter your information on the form below</p>


                    <form id="familyMember-form" method="post" action="familyMember.php" role="form">

                        <div class="messages"></div>

                        <div class="controls">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_firstname">Firstname *</label>
                                        <input id="form_firstname" type="text" name="firstName" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your firstname *" required="required" data-error="Firstname is required.">
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_lastname">Lastname *</label>
                                        <input id="form_lastname" type="text" name="lastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your lastname *" required="required" data-error="Lastname is required.">
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_email">Email *</label>
                                        <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your email *" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_cellPhone">Cell Phone</label>
                                        <input id="form_cellPhone" type="tel" name="cellPhone" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your cell phone number">
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_password">Password*</label>
                                        <input id="form_password" type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your password*">
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_passwordConfirmation">Confirm Password*</label>
                                        <input id="form_passwordConfirmation" type="password" name="passwordConfirmation" class="form-control" placeholder="Please confirm your password*">
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_familyCode">Family Code *</label>
                                        <input id="form_familyCode" name="familyCode" class="form-control" placeholder="Please Enter Family Code *" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Please,leave us a message.">
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <p></p>
                                    <p class="text-muted"><strong>*</strong> These fields are required.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </form>

                </div><!-- /.8 -->

            </div> <!-- /.row-->

        </div> <!-- /.container-->

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="validator.js"></script>
        <script src="familyMember.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my php

```
        $okMessage = 'Family member has successfully added.';
        $errorMessage = 'there was an error';

        try
        {
            $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=mydb', "user", "password");
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            $output = 'Unable to connect to the database server:' . $e->getMessage();
            include 'output.html.php';
            exit();
        }
        //$output = 'Database connection established.';
        //include 'output.html.php';

        $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
        //echo $firstName;
        //echo '<br>';

        $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
        //echo $lastName;
        //echo '<br>';

        $email = $_POST['email'];
        //echo $email;
        //echo '<br>';

        $cellPhone = $_POST['cellPhone'];
        //echo $cellPhone;
        //echo '<br>';

        $password = $_POST['password'];
        //echo $password;
        //echo '<br>';

        $familyCode = $_POST['familyCode'];
        //echo $familyCode;
        //echo '<br>';

        try{
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO familyMembers(FirstName, LastName, Email, Password, cell_phone, familyCode)
        Values(:FirstName, :LastName, :Email, :Password, :cell_phone, :familyCode)';

        $statement = $pdo -> prepare($sql);

        $statement -> execute(array(':FirstName' => $firstName, ':LastName' =>$lastName, ':Email'=> $email, ':Password'=> $password, ':cell_phone' => $cellPhone, ':familyCode' => $familyCode));

        $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
        }

        catch (\Exception $e){

        $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);

        }
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
            $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

            header('Content-Type: application/json');

            echo $encoded;
        }
        else {
            echo $responseArray['message'];
        }
```

Here is my javascript

```
    $(function () {

    $('#familyMember-form').validator();

    $('#familyMember-form').on('submit', function (e) {
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "familyMember.php";
            alert(url);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data)
                {
                    alert(url);
                    alert(data);
                    var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                    var messageText = data.message;
                    alert(messageAlert);
                    alert(messageText);

                    var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
                    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                        $('#familyMember-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                        $('#familyMember-form')[0].reset();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```